# How to animate div elements with auto scroll in Loop?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, scroll, infinite-scroll

I am developing a website and I need a help to improve a auto-scroll and looping animation to div content with JS. What I am trying to do is to animate the content inside #left-size ( .maintitle, .subtitle, .img).

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
    <title> MDC 22-23 </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="vertical-accordion">
        
        <!-- PROJECT 1 -->
        <li>
          <div class="projects">
              <div id="split-left">
                      <div class="maintitle"> Networked Infrastructures</div>
                      <div class="subtitle"> Three geographies (environmental, economic, political)</div>
                      <img src="gif5.gif">
                      <img src="gif4 (1).gif">
                      <img src="gif5.gif">
              </div>
              <div id="split-right">
                      <div class="sinopsis">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris consectetur ex lectus, eu dignissim est gravida ut. Aliquam ut nisi vitae risus tristique fermentum. Maecenas mattis pharetra nunc nec eleifend. Pellentesque vitae tempus mi, at consequat massa. Fusce pharetra enim id ultrices blandit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla cursus velit nec dui semper, vitae feugiat nisi congue. Duis a justo vitae enim ornare elementum vel eu quam. Vestibulum rutrum ut ligula ut suscipit. Nam luctus feugiat mi, a facilisis dui ullamcorper eget. Ut pellentesque, ante sit amet facilisis molestie, libero lectus faucibus metus, eu bibendum mauris urna in diam. Sed sit amet consectetur diam. Cras vel arcu non felis ultricies convallis quis non leo. Morbi non ipsum sit amet lectus dignissim mollis in sit amet augue.

                      Donec efficitur neque vitae dolor porttitor maximus. Donec ac enim in eros posuere sagittis id quis turpis. Duis volutpat augue eu enim vulputate, a bibendum enim euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc placerat dictum lacus, et imperdiet dolor finibus et. Aliquam ut mauris feugiat, mollis lacus non, maximus est. Curabitur ut tristique ante. Praesent laoreet enim vulputate accumsan congue. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
                      
                      Integer nisl dolor, tempor nec venenatis sit amet, euismod eget turpis. Donec ornare at lorem ut ultrices. Pellentesque tellus sem, commodo at accumsan at, vulputate non nulla. Nullam viverra nunc id sapien finibus, sed rhoncus risus porttitor. Suspendisse potenti. Proin faucibus, nulla non varius condimentum, erat ligula consequat nisl, eu finibus ipsum risus vitae magna. Sed ultricies quam in velit fermentum lobortis. Curabitur accumsan nec felis at feugiat. In velit arcu, elementum a luctus et, fermentum mattis libero. Etiam magna nisl, suscipit eu feugiat eget, sodales et mi.</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </li>
      
      <!-- PROJECT 2 -->
      <li>
           <div class="projects">
               <div id="split-left">
                      <div class="maintitle">You are the Product</div>
                      <div class="subtitle"> Data extractivism in the post-internet era</div>
                       <img src="BS.gif">
                       <img src="diagram.gif">
               </div>
               <div id="split-right">
                       <div class="sinopsis">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris consectetur ex lectus, eu dignissim est gravida ut. Aliquam ut nisi vitae risus tristique fermentum. Maecenas mattis pharetra nunc nec eleifend. Pellentesque vitae tempus mi, at consequat massa. Fusce pharetra enim id ultrices blandit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla cursus velit nec dui semper, vitae feugiat nisi congue. Duis a justo vitae enim ornare elementum vel eu quam. Vestibulum rutrum ut ligula ut suscipit. Nam luctus feugiat mi, a facilisis dui ullamcorper eget. Ut pellentesque, ante sit amet facilisis molestie, libero lectus faucibus metus, eu bibendum mauris urna in diam. Sed sit amet consectetur diam. Cras vel arcu non felis ultricies convallis quis non leo. Morbi non ipsum sit amet lectus dignissim mollis in sit amet augue.

                       Donec efficitur neque vitae dolor porttitor maximus. Donec ac enim in eros posuere sagittis id quis turpis. Duis volutpat augue eu enim vulputate, a bibendum enim euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc placerat dictum lacus, et imperdiet dolor finibus et. Aliquam ut mauris feugiat, mollis lacus non, maximus est. Curabitur ut tristique ante. Praesent laoreet enim vulputate accumsan congue. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
                       
                       Integer nisl dolor, tempor nec venenatis sit amet, euismod eget turpis. Donec ornare at lorem ut ultrices. Pellentesque tellus sem, commodo at accumsan at, vulputate non nulla. Nullam viverra nunc id sapien finibus, sed rhoncus risus porttitor. Suspendisse potenti. Proin faucibus, nulla non varius condimentum, erat ligula consequat nisl, eu finibus ipsum risus vitae magna. Sed ultricies quam in velit fermentum lobortis. Curabitur accumsan nec felis at feugiat. In velit arcu, elementum a luctus et, fermentum mattis libero. Etiam magna nisl, suscipit eu feugiat eget, sodales et mi.</div>
               </div>
           </div>
      </li>
   
       <!-- PROJECT 3 -->
   
       <li>
           <div class="projects">
               <div id="split-left">
                      <div class="maintitle">The Post-Truth Survival Guide</div>
                      <div class="subtitle">A Lexicon &amp; 10 Commndments</div>
                       <img src="gifgif.gif">
                       <img src="jo13.jpeg">
                       <img src="jo12.jpeg">
               </div>
               <div id="split-right">
                       <div class="sinopsis">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris consectetur ex lectus, eu dignissim est gravida ut. Aliquam ut nisi vitae risus tristique fermentum. Maecenas mattis pharetra nunc nec eleifend. Pellentesque vitae tempus mi, at consequat massa. Fusce pharetra enim id ultrices blandit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla cursus velit nec dui semper, vitae feugiat nisi congue. Duis a justo vitae enim ornare elementum vel eu quam. Vestibulum rutrum ut ligula ut suscipit. Nam luctus feugiat mi, a facilisis dui ullamcorper eget. Ut pellentesque, ante sit amet facilisis molestie, libero lectus faucibus metus, eu bibendum mauris urna in diam. Sed sit amet consectetur diam. Cras vel arcu non felis ultricies convallis quis non leo. Morbi non ipsum sit amet lectus dignissim mollis in sit amet augue.

                       Donec efficitur neque vitae dolor porttitor maximus. Donec ac enim in eros posuere sagittis id quis turpis. Duis volutpat augue eu enim vulputate, a bibendum enim euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc placerat dictum lacus, et imperdiet dolor finibus et. Aliquam ut mauris feugiat, mollis lacus non, maximus est. Curabitur ut tristique ante. Praesent laoreet enim vulputate accumsan congue. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
                       
                       Integer nisl dolor, tempor nec venenatis sit amet, euismod eget turpis. Donec ornare at lorem ut ultrices. Pellentesque tellus sem, commodo at accumsan at, vulputate non nulla. Nullam viverra nunc id sapien finibus, sed rhoncus risus porttitor. Suspendisse potenti. Proin faucibus, nulla non varius condimentum, erat ligula consequat nisl, eu finibus ipsum risus vitae magna. Sed ultricies quam in velit fermentum lobortis. Curabitur accumsan nec felis at feugiat. In velit arcu, elementum a luctus et, fermentum mattis libero. Etiam magna nisl, suscipit eu feugiat eget, sodales et mi.</div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </li>

       <!-- PROJECT 4 -->


       <li>4</li>
       <li>5</li>
       <li>6</li>
       <li>7</li>
       <li>8</li>
       <li>9</li>
       <li>10</li>
       <li>11</li>
       <li>12</li>
   </ul>
<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('ul#vertical-accordion > li').forEach( (li,_,all) =>
  {
  li.onclick =_=>
    {
    if (li.classList.toggle('selected'))
      {
      all.forEach( aLi => aLi.classList.toggle('selected',aLi===li));
      }
    }  
  });
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Content.

```
body {
  width  : 100vw;
  height : 100vh;
  margin : 0;
}

ul,
li {
  margin     : 0;
  padding    : 0;
  list-style : none;
}

ul {
  display  : flex;
  overflow : hidden;
  height   : 100vh;
  width    : 100vw;
}

li {
  overflow-y         : scroll;
  overflow           : auto;
  -webkit-box-flex   : 1;
  -webkit-flex       : 1;
  -ms-flex           : 1;
  flex               : 1;
  height             : 100vh;
  -webkit-transition : -webkit-box-flex 500ms ease-out;
  -webkit-transition : -webkit-flex 500ms ease-out;
  transition         : -webkit-box-flex 500ms ease-out;
  transition         : -ms-flex 500ms ease-out;
  transition         : flex 500ms ease-out;
  padding            : 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow : 2px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
  -moz-box-shadow    : 2px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
  box-shadow         : 2px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
}

ul#vertical-accordion:not(:hover) li.selected,
li:hover {
  -webkit-box-flex : 50vw;
  -webkit-flex     : 50vw;
  -ms-flex         : 50vw;
  flex             : 50vw;
}

.projects{
  width           : 50vw;
  height          : 100vh;
  display         : flex;
  flex-direction  : row;
  margin-bottom   : 5vh;
}

#split-left{
  width                               : 50%;
  height                              : auto;
  /* scroll animation  
  -webkit-animation-name              : move;
  -webkit-animation-duration          : 8s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count   : infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction         : up;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function   :linear;*/
}

/* #split-left:hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state  : paused;
}


@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0% {
     transform:translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
     transform:translateY(-100%);
  }
}*/

#split-right{
  width: 50%;
}

/* ------- PARAGRAPH STYLES ------- */

a {
  text-decoration : none;
  color           : black;
}

a:hover {
  opacity : 0.5;
}

.maintitle {
  width          : 100%;
  font-size      : 30px;
  text-transform : uppercase;
  font-family    : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.subtitle {
  width       : 100;
  font-size   : 20px;
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

img{
  width   : 100%;
  height  : auto;
}
  
.sinopsis{
  position     : relative;
  font-family  : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size    : 15px;
  padding-left : 20px;
}
```

I try it with Css but the looping is not working perfectly, and it starts in the before it reachs the ends of the div content.

Comment: More info about exactly what you're trying to accomplish with the animation would be helpful context for those who take a look into your issue... What animations are you trying to trigger and when? How does this relate to auto-scroll?

I may be able to help, depends on what your answers are (:

Comment: Hello, I am trying to make a animation similar to this website: https://ext.maat.pt/topics. So i want to the element inside the div #left-side, to be in auto scroll and in loop. What happens with the css animation, is that the loop breaks in the middle of loading the content. :)